# Help with Green functions of Wightman fields

Tags: quantum-field-theory, greens-functions, correlation-functions, wightman-fields

I am trying to prove equation 97 in Chapter I of Zavialov's "Renormalized Quantum Field Theory" book, the statement claims that the Green functions of Wightman fields $\check{\phi}$, defined by
$$\langle0 | T\left\{\check{\phi}(x_1)\cdots \check{\phi}(x_n)\right\} | 0\rangle$$
can be calculated as
$$\langle0 | T\left\{\phi(x_1)\cdots \phi(x_n)S(\phi)\right\} | 0\rangle.$$

The definition I have for the Wightman field $\check{\phi}$ is
$$\check{\phi}(x) = S^\dagger \otimes T\{\phi(x)S(\phi)\}$$
where $S$ is the S-matrix. From where we can prove
$$\check{\phi}(x) = \phi(x) -i \int D^{ret}(x-y)\left(S^\dagger \otimes \frac{\delta S}{\delta \phi(y)}\right)dy.$$

The definition of the $\otimes$ product is
$$A(\phi)\otimes B(\phi) = \left.\exp\left(-i\int D^-(x-y)\frac{\delta}{\delta \phi_1(x)}\frac{\delta}{\delta \phi(y)}\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y\right)A(\phi_1)B(\phi_2)\right|_{\phi_1=\phi_2=\phi}$$

And the definition of the $T$-product is the same but with the $D^c(x-y)$ function.

Can anyone point me in the correct direction for the proof?

I tried to do the simpler case, with only one field, then the relation is
$$\langle0 | \check{\phi}(x) | 0\rangle=\langle0 | T\left\{\phi(x)S(\phi)\right\} | 0\rangle.$$
The time-order can be calculated as
$$T\left\{\phi(x)S(\phi)\right\} = :\phi(x) S(\phi): -i\int D^c(x-y)\frac{\delta S}{\delta \phi(y)}\mathrm{d}y$$
And the vev is given by the second term
$$\langle0 | T\left\{\phi(x)S(\phi)\right\} | 0\rangle = -i\int D^c(x-y)S_1(y)\mathrm{d}y.$$
with $S_1(y) = \langle0 | \frac{\delta S}{\delta \phi(y)} | 0\rangle$.
But I couldn't calculate $\langle0 | \check{\phi}(x) | 0\rangle$.

Comment: @Qmechanic, the equation I'm refering to is from a book (https://www.google.com/books/edition/_/SIczAQAAIAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=0).